# VB.NET Teclado windows 10 (TabTip.exe) no se ve

Tags: vb.net, teclado

Estoy invocando al teclado de Windows 10, en una aplicación windows forms, pero éste aunque aparece en el panel de taeas,[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] no se ve en pantalla. Aquí dejo el código de como lo invoco. ¿Alguna idea?

```
    Dim TabTip = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"

    Try
        If IO.File.Exists(TabTip) Then
            Using proces = New Process()
                proces.StartInfo.FileName = TabTip

                proces.Start()
            End Using
        Else
            Log("El teclado no se encuentra en: " & TabTip)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log("Error al abrir el teclado.", ex)
    End Try
```

Comment: Creo que tienes que usar ProcessStartInfo para poder ejecutarlo y mostrar la UI al usuario.

Comment: El caso es que funciona correctamente en todos los PCs en los que he probado excepto en 1. Y no sé que es lo que hace que en ese en concreto no aparezca.

Comment: Has probado a ejectar la aplicación como administrador en el equipo en el que no te funciona?

Comment: Sí. He de decir que el PC tiene 2 monitores, pero no sale en ninguno.

Comment: Bueno, parece que cuando una pantalla es táctil hay que activar en la configuración del teclado una nueva opción que aparece. El problema ahora es conseguir que siempre se abra en la pantalla dende se ejecuta la aplicación (secundaria), porque en estos momentos lo hace de manera aleatoria entre las 2.

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar esto en un evento:

```
Process.Start("osk.exe")
```

Con eso me funciono ok.

Slds!

Comment: Bienvenido, gracias por tu contribución, agrega una explicación de lo que realiza lo que agregas en tu respuesta, revisar [answer]. no olvides realizar el [tour] saludos!.